# NextJS app with auth0/nextjs-auth0 gets unauthorized / access_denied response for oauth/token request

Tags: next.js, oauth, auth0

I'm trying to make test nextjs app for oauth authorization with [auth0/nextjs-auth0 library](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0), using their [interactive manual](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nextjs/interactive).

I've set up layout and routes exactly as in the manual above.

My local server runs on `http://localhost:3000`, I'm testing only it for beginning.

I've set up addresses in auth0 application dashboard for `http://localhost:3000/` and `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback`.

I tried to set both application types there: 'Regular Web Application' and 'Single Page Application'.

I'm getting server console error after (successfull?) authorization cycle:

```
CallbackHandlerError: Callback handler failed. CAUSE: access_denied (Unauthorized)
```

I've seen a lot of questions about this issue as on stackoverflow, auth0 community site and on github. But in none of these discussions I could see a solution for my case.

Actually, it happens when browser has redirected to final callback (with url like `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback?code=kMh43xvyzlUswz4YHzrWAQ_FCon0Y2qzEcgPgPdB7ltJy&state=eyJyZXR1cm5UbyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6MzAwMCJ9`).

I've made some research and it's turned out that I receive 401 error on `oauth/token` response (via `@auth0/nextjs-auth0/dist/auth0-session/client` and `openid-client/lib` and execution of the server nextjs part fails on exception in `processResponse` method of `node_modules/openid-client/lib/helpers/process_response.js`):

```
POST https://dev-2hnwky81m58gjr4c.us.auth0.com/oauth/token
```

With headers:

```
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic {{base 64 encoded client id and client secret}}
User-Agent: nextjs-auth0/3.2.0
Host: dev-2hnwky81m58gjr4c.us.auth0.com
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
content-length: 205
```

Decoded 'Authorization' field here is for my (client id:client secret) data.

Payload data:

```
{
  "grant_type": "authorization_code",
  "code": "yZSKmo9a_JXFyTDftfl1p7yH_tmlrj746oZ5DKHP-9dy7",
  "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback",
  "code_verifier": "1TgZFvhugtMtSf-t-PaIC87qLOzXMyK-BvFK4zhacew"
}
```

Response headers:

```
Date: Mon, 23 Oct 2023 20:13:21 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 60
Connection: close
CF-Ray: 81aca3dc68c74b53-BKK
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
Cache-Control: private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, no-transform
Set-Cookie: did=s%3Av0%3A9ceb1890-71e0-11ee-9973-59fbc72fd88b.cDOTXG%2BaiPIBIrh7CPbPW%2ByN9P1A5tseRpVHAWuYxgA; Max-Age=31557600; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 23 Oct 2024 02:13:21 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Vary: Origin
ot-baggage-auth0-request-id: 81aca3dc68c74b53
ot-tracer-sampled: true
ot-tracer-spanid: 2b427f830af9129a
ot-tracer-traceid: 79d215886dc44a72
Set-Cookie: did_compat=s%3Av0%3A9ceb1890-71e0-11ee-9973-59fbc72fd88b.cDOTXG%2BaiPIBIrh7CPbPW%2ByN9P1A5tseRpVHAWuYxgA; Max-Age=31557600; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 23 Oct 2024 02:13:21 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
traceparent: 00-000000000000000079d215886dc44a72-2b427f830af9129a-01
tracestate: auth0-request-id=81aca3dc68c74b53,auth0=true
X-Auth0-RequestId: 304168aa5a74829f8894
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-RateLimit-Limit: 300
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 299
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1698092002
Server: cloudflare
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400
```

Response body:

```
{
  "error": "access_denied",
  "error_description": "Unauthorized"
}
```

My `.env.local` config:

```
AUTH0_SECRET={{My auth0 secret code}}
AUTH0_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000
AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL=https://dev-2hnwky81m58gjr4c.us.auth0.com
AUTH0_CLIENT_ID={{My auth0 client id}}
AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET={{My local generated secret code}}
```

Used library and tool versions:

- @auth0/nextjs-auth0: 3.2.0
- next: 13.5.6
- react: 18.2.0
- npm: 9.5.1
- node: v18.16.0

What is my mistake? What and where should I fix?

I've tried to trace the error deeply (explained it in my question), tried to find solution in discussions for similar questions on stackoverflow, auth0 community site and on github. I expect some advice to solve this problem or to find more specific reason of it.